# While importing scss file into parent class css not working properly

Tags: angular, sass, angular-cli-v9

Below is my scss file

```
.mat {
@import "ej2-base/styles/material.scss";
@import "ej2-buttons/styles/material.scss";
@import "ej2-popups/styles/material.scss";
@import "ej2-splitbuttons/styles/material.scss";
}
.boot{
    @import "ej2-base/styles/bootstrap.scss";
    @import "ej2-buttons/styles/bootstrap.scss";
    @import "ej2-popups/styles/bootstrap.scss";
    @import "ej2-splitbuttons/styles/bootstrap.scss";
}
```

In here, i want to load material theme while changing class to the body.But styles not get added

Here i have attched my sample
[scsssIssue.zip](https://github.com/sass/sass/files/5051266/scsssIssue.zip)

### Repo steps

- Download above sample
- GIve `npm i` command then `ng serve`
- you will see button in browser
- Then click `click me` button - style wont get added'

if you chage scss like below

```
@import "ej2-base/styles/material.scss";
@import "ej2-buttons/styles/material.scss";
@import "ej2-popups/styles/material.scss";
@import "ej2-splitbuttons/styles/material.scss";
```

Style getting added properly.

> Reference : https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/2888

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an issue with angular nor with sass but rather with the component library you're using. Since they're using a lot of `#{&}`'s for scoping, your root selector (e.g. `.mat`) will be re-used / duplicated and creates rules such as:

```
.mat .mat.e-btn { }
```

Notice the second `.mat` which is created by a their [`#{&}.e-btn`](https://github.com/syncfusion/ej2-javascript-ui-controls/blob/master/controls/buttons/styles/button/_layout.scss#L3) selector.

Comment: HI @naeramarth7, i am new to sass. Ca you please little more clear. Am i have to change anything from my scss files syntax......Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey @kumaresan_sd, the issue is not on your side – and from my point of view there's no easy way to fix this. This is an issue by [ej2](https://github.com/syncfusion/ej2-javascript-ui-controls#readme) not allowing a nested import by the way they uses the _parent selector_. Some libraries come with a _mixin_ to setup the styles, but ej2 does not seem to do so – your best bet might be to as for help at ej2.

Comment: HI @naeramarth, Thank you so much for validating my issue. Actually i am from ej2. i just want find some way to resolve this issue i mean syntax chages. Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there actually a reason for prefixing top level selectors in a library with `#{&}` ?

Comment: thank you so much for your suggestion while `#{&}` removing this it generates proper css and theme applied fine

Comment: @naeramath7,  is there any alternate scoping available instead of `#{&}` since i am using this to differentiate my 'two` kind of styles like `kumar-mat1` and kumar-mat2`

Comment: @kumaresan_sd you can still differentiate by importing within `kumar-mat1` and `kumar-mat2` but the top level selectors (`#{&}`) **in the library** need to be removed, since they are duplicating your selectors.

Comment: i think you misunderstood my problem, i have two jind of component like `ej-button` and `ej2-button` both using same classes like "e-btn". to provide compatible support i have used that selector which avoids that css overlapping when using both ej and ej2 button in same page